# How do I display user selection when the user is asked to select 4 out of 12 options?

Tags: java, android

I have an activity where the user is asked to build a meal. Here they are presented with 12 food options to choose from (represented as image buttons). I want the user to be able to click on four of these image buttons and continue to the next activity. However, I do not know how to show the 4 user selected image buttons on the next activity. I have tried using the putExtra() and getExtra() commands, but i cannot seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
//The Images you want, save as bitmap
imageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap image= imageView.getDrawingCache();

//Create a extras bundle and put bitmap in with key
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putParcelable("imagebitmap", image);

//Create a new intent and pass in the bundle
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(intent);

//In next activity, grab the extras
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
//Get the saved bitmap with the key value into a bitmap object
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.getParcelable("imagebitmap");
//Set it
image.setImageBitmap(bmp );
```

As for the logic behind that, I can't really help as I don't see your code. But I would establish onClickListeners on all the imageviews and keep track of what's being clicked

```
imgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {

    if (count < 4) {
        imgView.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap image= imageView.getDrawingCache();
        extras.putParcelable("imagebitmap" + count, image);
    } else {
        //Tell them to deselect, or add an operation to deselect, and decrement counter
    }
    }
});
```